# Multiple edits within the edit window no longer preserve all edit comments

Tags: bug, status-completed, revisions-list, edit-summary

I just edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685877/how-can-i-use-perl-and-rrd-to-plot-ping-times) twice: once to reformat the code (it was included in a `<pre>` block), and again to add a direct image link. Because I made these edits within a few minutes of each other, they were folded into one edit in the revision history. However, the revision comment for my first edit ("formatting fixes") is entirely lost.

I'm pretty sure that comments used to be concatenated together with semicolons. This was preferable behaviour to losing all but the final revision comment.

Comment: yes, I can confirm this by making multiple non-visible edits to this post

Comment: It did work that way once. Then it was broken completely (editing twice lost all comments). Then it started doing the current thing (where multiple edits with comments preserve the last comment, but edits without comments merely append a short description of the change, e.g. "Improved formatting; edited title; edited tags"). There may have been other weirdness involved at some point as well... Personally, I'm just happy they fixed the "lost all comments now and forever" bug.

Comment: The related questions generated from the title of planned questions do work some times :-) I was going to write up this bug once I confirmed it [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/51901/revisions) compared to [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/53157/revisions).

Comment: Has this bug made any progress to being resolved yet?  As long as there is no summary, the previous summaries are preserved.  But I often always add summaries to my edits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We now retain the last edit summary when you're quick editing:

[Bring up original edit summary when editing your prior edit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93164/bring-up-original-edit-summary-when-editing-your-prior-edit/96454#96454)

Comment: Why don't you concatenate both (or all) edit summaries?

Comment: +1 for fixing the issue, but it appears to be occurring again.

Comment: @todofixthis there was a bug introduced with functionality for the new review dashboard; a fix will be deployed soon.

Comment: At the time of writing, it seems like none of the edit summaries except for the first one is saved when a user quick edits.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to at least warn the user reediting that previous edit summary will be lost if it is more recent that 5 minutes.