# Edit message is lost after a small follow-up edit

Tags: bug, edit-summary

I've noticed a glitch here:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/21220580/revisions

What I did was:

1. post a very short, speculative answer
2. did some more research, came back later and provided a working example; edited my previous answer with summary like "expanded; yadda yadda.."
3. followed up with a tiny edit with summary "more traceback clarity"

Edits 2 and 3 were collapsed into one (standard behaviour), but  the edit summary from the substantial edit has been completely replaced with the fixup's, which doesn't look correct to me.

Comment: because you made these edits within a few minutes of each other, they were folded into one edit in the revision history but as far as edit summary is concerned [this has been discussed here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/96947/221351)

Comment: Moderator: I suggest to retag `status-bydesign`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit the post **during the grace period of the previous edit**, you will see the edit summary of that edit. This feature is implemented after [this request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93164/187824). So you have overridden the edit summary of the first edit.

May be this is the case why you didn't notice it. You may have used <kbd>Tab</kbd> button to go to the edit summary from the post body which selects all texts like this:

> [image]

and writing anything would have override the text.

I just tested the same [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216902/187824).

Comment: Oh, so it's not a bug because I'm able know beforehand if my edit will be a real (named) edit or just a fixup to previous edit, and I'm expected to adjust my messaging accordingly. Wasn't obvious to me at all, but makes sense, thank you!

Comment: it is not understandable. they should more clearly say about their behaviour.